# Two text with same style, but one has numbering in MS Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, text-formatting

I have two text with same Style (Heading 1) as seen in this picture with names *text1* and *text2*:

[image]

I'm wondering how one of them has numbering while the other does't?!
Note that removing numbering causes some formatting differences, so the *text2* has not created by removing numbering from *text1*. But how it has created?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a non-arabic font and left to right formatting? I don't understand Persian so I can't make sense of your screenshot :/

Comment: DavidPostill, I can't reproduce the text2 (my question is exactly here)!

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple types of style, character and paragraph. If you really want to know the difference you need to show the formatting used though I can't recall if word has a command for that.

Alternatively rename the document from .DOCX to .ZIP and then check the contents manually to see the physical differences.

One side note, you can always use the format painter to ensure both are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I find out what was the problem. Consider that the Style Heading 1 has Numbering. I format text1 with that and so it naturally gets a number. Now, if there be a ***new line*** after the page break of text1, then the text after that (here is text2) affects the numbering and gets a new number. However, if there isn't any ***new line*** character after the **page break**, Word doesn't produce any number while the numbering is On. As seen in picture, there is no ***new line*** character and so word hasn't produced number for the text2.